# java.io.IOException While invoking webService from Service

Tags: android, web-services, service

I am invoking web service from my application. I have used Service instead of `ASyncTask` to invoke the web service. I am getting `java.io.IOException`. I have tested with `AsyncTask` also but its working fine. Problem is only when i use `Service`(background thread). Please help me to resolve this issue.

Logcat is

```
04-02 17:01:30.103: W/System.err(17131): java.io.IOException
04-02 17:01:30.104: W/System.err(17131):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:87)
04-02 17:01:30.105: W/System.err(17131):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
04-02 17:01:30.105: W/System.err(17131):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:109)
04-02 17:01:30.106: W/System.err(17131):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:157)
04-02 17:01:30.107: W/System.err(17131):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
04-02 17:01:30.108: W/System.err(17131):    at com.example.rajneta.Syncdetails.send_voter_record(Syncdetails.java:204)
04-02 17:01:30.108: W/System.err(17131):    at com.example.rajneta.Syncdetails.onStartCommand(Syncdetails.java:62)
04-02 17:01:30.109: W/System.err(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2638)
04-02 17:01:30.110: W/System.err(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:149)
04-02 17:01:30.111: W/System.err(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
04-02 17:01:30.112: W/System.err(17131):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 17:01:30.113: W/System.err(17131):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-02 17:01:30.114: W/System.err(17131):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
04-02 17:01:30.115: W/System.err(17131):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 17:01:30.116: W/System.err(17131):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 17:01:30.117: W/System.err(17131):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
04-02 17:01:30.118: W/System.err(17131):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
04-02 17:01:30.119: W/System.err(17131):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code :**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    send_voter_record();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public void send_voter_record() {
    SoapObject request = null;
    try {
        String query;
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("data", query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    System.out.println("###########request" + request);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.XSD;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object root = envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please, Show your Logcat output as well as show your service code

Comment: better to call that webservice in AsyncTask.

Comment: I know AsyncTask is better option, but i want to sync many records that were previously not synced due to network problem. So whenever network  will be available i am calling web service in background thread. If i use AsyncTask then user will not be able to do UI interaction until it finishes.

Comment: but i had searched on google but didn't found exact cause of your issue. so told you to use AsyncTask. what UI operation you wanna do while calling web service.?

Comment: Any UI interaction, not any specific.. Anyways if no other option is there, at the end that's the only solution..To do it with AsyncTask..

Comment: what kinda of error or issue come if you use AsyncTask.?

Comment: Nothing, It's working fine with AsyncTask.. Only disadvantage is UI interaction will not be possible..

Comment: do you need to use the data which is coming from webservice is required in UI to show.?

Comment: No... I am just posting the data, not fetching any data

Comment: then no it will not block your UI. you just need to call web service in AsyncTask. show your AsyncTask Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically **Services** is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.
And **AsyncTask** allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Working with web-services, you have to call it **Asynchronously**, because asynchronous invocation enables Web service clients to initiate a request to a Web service, continue processing without blocking, and receive the response at some point in the future.

So,

As per your app requirement, You have to call web-service using Services. But what you have done is, You are calling your web-service direct in Services, instead of that, **just call your web-service into asynctask and call async task from service**. Thats all.

Get back with your feedback.

**Happy coding...**

Comment: Ok.. I will try it :)

Comment: Yes, It's working amazing now.. :) I have searched for this issue for long time but did not get any solution.. Your suggestion totally solved my issue..Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your code.
You just start the background service and in onStart method of service call the method to invoke web service and stop the service after the back ground process get completed.